# React Native version mismatch, can't rebuild in Xcode

Tags: react-native

When running `react-native run-ios` (simulator) I get the following error (React Native error message in the simulator):

```
console.error: "React Native version mismatch.

JavaScript version: 0.61.5
Native version: 0.60.3

Make sure that you have rebuilt the native code. If the problem persists try clearing the Watchman and packager caches with `watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`."

_construct
    construct.js:30:26
Wrapper
    wrapNativeSuper.js:26:23
SyntheticError
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:28736:111
reactConsoleErrorHandler
    ExceptionsManager.js:135:52
checkVersions
    ReactNativeVersionCheck.js:31:6
<global>
    checkNativeVersion.js:17
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
<global>
    InitializeCore.js:42:9
loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:322:6
guardedLoadModule
    require.js:201:45
global code
    index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false:149289:4
```

I've tried running `watchman watch-del-all` as well as `react-native start --reset-cache` but the problem persists. I tried cleaning the project in Xcode and rebuilding it, but when building in Xcode I get the error `clang: error: no such file or directory: '.../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGMarker.cpp'`. Searching through the project, I can't find any references to the `YGMarker.cpp` file.

This is the packages I'm using

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.7.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "class-transformer": "^0.2.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-launch-navigator": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-sms": "^1.10.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "serializr": "^1.5.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.60.25",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
}
```

Comment: Just close your bundler in the terminal and rebuild it again

Answer (score 0):

Please find out you have twice package.json file in your project, Please remove on unwanted file your issue will be resolve.

Answer (score 0):

goto your project directory and run `killall node -9` and restart your server using `react-native start`,

reload you application again.